# How do I add a non-remote method a model in Loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs

How can I add a local method to a Model *instance*? In other words, a method on the model instance that will be executed by the server, and not exposed over the rest interface.

What I want to be able to do on the server is run:

```
Person.findById(1, (err, person) => {
    let b = person.customFunction();
});
```

but I do not want `customFunction` exposed over the rest interface.

I know you can create a remote method on a model like this:

```
module.exports = function(Person){

    Person.greet = function(msg, cb) {
      cb(null, 'Greetings... ' + msg);
    }

    Person.remoteMethod(
        'greet', 
        {
          accepts: {arg: 'msg', type: 'string'},
          returns: {arg: 'greeting', type: 'string'}
        }
    );
};
```

And I know if you leave off the call to `Person.remoteMethod()` you will have added a server-only method to Model class itself, but that isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy, you just use Javascript's prototype functionality. In Person.js, just add this:

```
Person.prototype.customFunction = function() {
   console.log('my custom code');
};
```

Then, give an `person` instance, you can call:

```
person.customFunction();
```